# BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 52: Method shuffle does not exist. - after running composer update

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, lumen

I just updated my dependencies (composer update) on my current Lumen 5.3 project to their most recent versions.
Now everything seems to be broken, out of the box all the `illuminate/*` dependencies were updated to v5.3.23 which seems to have quite a few differences with v5.3.16.

The first issue I found was that the namespace defined in a route group, it's not needed anymore.

This code (that used to work just fine)

```
$app->group(['prefix' => '{storeId}', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () use ($app) {
    ....
});
```

it's now giving back a ReflectionException because

`Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\MyController.php does not exists`.

Well, that's an easy fix, I just removed the namespace and it worked

```
$app->group(['prefix' => '{storeId}'], function () use ($app) {
    ....
});
```

Now I am getting a really weird error that makes no sense to me:

`BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 52: Method shuffle does not exist.`.

That exception is thrown every time I try to use Eloquent. Just to be clear, I cannot find any method `shuffle` in my codebase and the only references in the `vendor` folder are related to `fzaninotto/faker` and `illuminate/collection`.

It seems that the only way to fix the issue is to "downgrade" lumen to v5.2.* (I tried with v5.3.1 in my composer.json but it still brings all the illuminate packages v5.3.23).

These are the dependencies updated

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.2.0)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.3)
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.4)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/contracts (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/contracts (v5.3.23)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing illuminate/filesystem (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/filesystem (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/container (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/container (v5.3.23)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing illuminate/events (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/events (v5.3.23)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing illuminate/view (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/view (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/validation (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/validation (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/translation (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/translation (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/console (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/console (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/queue (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/queue (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/pipeline (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/pipeline (v5.3.23)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing illuminate/pagination (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/pagination (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/session (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/session (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/http (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/http (v5.3.23)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing illuminate/hashing (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/hashing (v5.3.23)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing illuminate/encryption (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/encryption (v5.3.23)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing illuminate/database (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/database (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/config (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/config (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/cache (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/cache (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/bus (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/bus (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/broadcasting (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/broadcasting (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing illuminate/auth (v5.3.16)
  - Installing illuminate/auth (v5.3.23)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing laravel/lumen-framework (v5.3.1)
  - Installing laravel/lumen-framework (v5.3.2)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.19.23)
  - Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.19.24)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.2)
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing phpunit/phpunit (5.6.2)
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (5.6.3)
    Downloading: 100%

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this error around the same time this morning.

1. Remove the namespace in the routes.
2. Update composer a second time.

What I discovered, when I ran composer info, is that Illuminate/Support did not update when the rest of the Illuminate packages did.

> illuminate/session v5.3.23 The Illuminate Session package.
>
> illuminate/support v5.3.16 The Illuminate Support package.
>
> illuminate/translation v5.3.23 The Illuminate Translation package.

The interesting thing is that originally, I did another composer update. But it did not resolve. So, what I did, was I back-dated the Laravel lumen package (ran composer update) and then updated again to the latest.

Something's just messed up in the package update process, I think.

Comment: Running again `composer update` solved the issue, actually I first downgraded lumen to `5.2.*`, removed the vendor folder and the composer.lock, then `composer install`, then I changed to `5.3.*` and did the the same process, this time the `illuminate/support` package was updated to `v5.3.23`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same thing. I just ran the update again and it updated illuminate/support. That fixed the problem for me. I think something got missed when they pushed the composer packages.